Geometry nodes: Raycast in two opposite directions simultaneously
I want to use raycast node in two directions: 0,0,-1 and 0,0,1
So can I avoid ugly nodesetup with two raycast nodes and use just one?


I don't think that's possible. Ray direction doesn't have an "S", so it's one direction only

You can always make a group out of these nodes if you want to tidy up your nodes.

I thought we can use source position socket to just offset to negative direction.
In my case we can plug postion node to source postion socket and just add some value to Z.
But we should consider ray direction socket and ray distance socket to keep node setup more all-purpose

Raycast have a single origin, and a single direction. If you want it to be all-purpose, grouping the nodes would be a good way, with a vector (0,0,1) as input and a Scale Vector set to -1.

Not possible. (But did you notice you're taking the position of the "not hit"? That means no position or 0,0,0)

(Using Blender 4.2.4)
Overview and Setup
The proposed approach is shifting the Source Position along the Ray Direction such that the new Source Position is on a bounding sphere of the Target Geometry, thus outside of the Target Geometry. Then a single ray is cast inwards this sphere.

Figure 1: Main GeometryNodes graph and setup for two lines targeting the default Cube, with its bounding sphere drawn as an Ico Sphere. Red dots are initial sources, blue dots are shifted sources, and yellow dots are hit positions.
For the demonstration, Source Position and Ray Direction are defined by a set of unconnected edges, such that per edge the first vertex is the Source and the Ray Direction is aligned with the edge.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.4+)
GeometryNodes Modifier

Figure 2: Nomenclature and group nodes.
Nomenclature

$C$: Bounding sphere center
$\vec{n}$: Ray direction, with $\| \vec{n} \| = 1$
$O$: Origin of the object to which the modifier is attached
$R$: Bounding sphere radius
$S$: Initial source
$S'$: Shifted source
$\lambda$: Signed shifting distance along $\vec{n}$

Main graph
(see Fig.1)
1. The Bounding Sphere group node is computing $R$ and $\vec{OC}$.
2. The Source group node is computing $\vec{OS'}$ and $\vec{n}$.
3. For the demonstration, shifted sources are displayed as Points. Their number is equal to the Edge Count of the object to which the modifier is attached.
4. The Raycast node intersects the Target Geometry with the ray from $S'$ along the direction $\vec{n}$. It is to notice that the Ray Length is set to $2R$, the largest distance inside the bounding sphere.
Bounding Sphere group node
The bounding sphere is oversized from the Target Geometry Bounding Box (see Fig.2 top left).
5. $C$ is computed as the center of this Bounding Box.
6. $R$ is computed as half the length  of this Bounding Box diagonal.
Source group node
(see Fig.2 bottom, and the Mathematics section thereafter)
7. The dark pink nodes are computing
$$
\Delta = R^2 - ( \vec{CS} )^2 + ( \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} )^2
$$
8. The dark green nodes are computing
$$
\lambda = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} + \sqrt{\Delta} & \textrm{if } \Delta \ge 0\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
9. The dark red nodes are computing
$$
\vec{OS'} = \vec{OS} - \lambda  \vec{n}
$$
10. $\vec{OS'}$ and $\vec{n}$ are evaluated using Sample Index nodes set in Edge domain.
Mathematics
The shifted source position $S'$ is defined by two relations:

$S$ and $S'$ are aligned along the direction $\vec{n}$. Consequently, $\vec{SS'} = -\lambda \vec{n}$. It is to notice that the minus sign is arbitrary ; it is chosen to simplify the algebra.
$S'$ is on the sphere with center $C$ and radius $R$. Consequently, $\| \vec{CS'} \| = R$.

It follows that:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
R^2 & = & ( \vec{CS'} )^2 \\
    & = & ( \vec{CS} + \vec{SS'} )^2 \\
    & = & ( \vec{CS} - \lambda \vec{n} )^2 \\
    & = & ( \vec{CS} )^2 - 2 \ \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} \ \lambda + \lambda^2
\end{array}
$$
Thus $\lambda$ is solution of the quadratic equation:
$$
\lambda^2 - 2 \ \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} \ \lambda + ( \vec{CS} )^2 - R^2 = 0
$$
Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant defined by:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Delta & = & ( \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} )^2 - \left\{ ( \vec{CS} )^2 - R^2 \right\} \\
    & = & R^2 - ( \vec{CS} )^2 + ( \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} )^2
\end{array}
$$
If $\Delta \lt 0$, there is no intersection between the straight line defined by $(S, \vec{n})$ and the sphere, so no intersection between the ray and the Target Geometry. Consequently, there is no need to shift $S$ and $\lambda$ is set to $0$. Otherwise, $\lambda$ is defined as:
$$
\lambda = \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} \pm \sqrt{\Delta}
$$
The $\pm$ sign is because there are two intersections between the straight line defined by $(S, \vec{n})$ and the sphere. The $+$ sign is chosen to shift $S'$ away from $S$ in the direction opposite to $\vec{n}$, to keep $+\vec{n}$ as Ray Direction. So if $\Delta \ge 0$, $\lambda$ is computed as:
$$
\lambda = \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} + \sqrt{\Delta}
$$
Eventually, $\vec{SS'} = -\lambda \vec{n}$ yields:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\vec{OS'} & = & \vec{OS} + \vec{SS'} \\
          & = & \vec{OS} - \lambda \vec{n}
\end{array}
$$
NB: the other root of the quadratic equation $\lambda = \vec{CS} \cdot \vec{n} - \sqrt{\Delta}$ can be used "to raycast" in $-\vec{n}$ direction.
